# Login first to access page - MVC Database-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-database-first

There are way to many code-first tutorial but I cannot find any good guide how to force user to register/login first to access the page via database-first solution.

Correct me if I'm wrong. As I've seen these code-first tutorial, they implement validations directly into EF-models. That way I may not be able to do for database-first solution, as everything will be removed once EF will re-create models once I update the database or so.

Is there any good guide how to do it?

Any help is much appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it possible in your case to use code first solution? I personally find them many times easier, especially when trying to implement things such as validation etc.

Comment: Just curious - if you mark your Main / Home controller as `[Authorize]`, won't that work?

Comment: In my case it's not possible, as I would  also prefer code-first. `[Authorize]` seems to do the trick as it force me to login. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment; in order to force application to go to Login page first, you have to decorate your `Main` / `Home` controller with `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: Btw, now as my pages required user to be logged in, how do I grant them access/authorization to visit these pages?

Comment: If user is logged in, he can automatically navigate to `[Authorize]` marked controllers, unless they are restricted only for specific user groups such as admins

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `ViewModel` which would make it possible to put the logic tied up with the `View` in your `ViewModel`. Using a `ViewModel` you could organize the data and add `Validations` on `ViewModel` than on the `Entity` in your model.

Suggested reads:

- http://rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp-net-mvc-applications

In terms of Authorization, it would be great to take a look at [this](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/simple.html) (concept is based on .NET Core, but can be handy)